# Stacking and shaping slices of DataFrame (pandas) without looping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of the following form:

```
     var1           var2        var3        day
0   -0.001284819    0.00138089  1.022781    1
1   -0.001310201    0.001377473 1.022626    1
2   -0.001330947    0.001374873 1.022477    2
3   -0.0013596      0.001430423 1.022385    2
4   -0.001361913    0.00144389  1.02228     3
5   -0.001371761    0.001440607 1.022161    3
6   -0.001393955    0.00143729  1.022017    4
7   -0.001431099    0.00143434  1.021908    4
8   -0.001466792    0.00143334  1.021749    5
9   -0.001491       0.00143159  1.021602    5
```

Each variable var1 to var3 is a time series and two samples are recorded every day. I'm trying to transform this DataFrame into something like this:

```
     day   1             2             3             4             5
0   var1  -0.001284819  -0.001330947  -0.001361913  -0.001393955  -0.001466792
1         -0.001310201  -0.0013596    -0.001371761  -0.001431099  -0.001491
2   var2   0.00138089    0.001374873   0.00144389    0.00143729    0.00143334
3          0.001377473   0.001430423   0.001440607   0.00143434    0.00143159
4   var3   1.022781      1.022477      1.02228       1.022017      1.021749
5          1.022626      1.022385      1.022161      1.021908      1.021602
```

Now each column is a day, and within each day, each variable is still in the same order as in the original time series.

I've been trying to figure out a way of achieving this result using pivoting, stacking and operations of this sort to avoid looping but so far I haven't be able to manage.

Any suggestions/hints/ideas on how to solve this would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily the prettiest, but in the past I've done things like

```
df = pd.read_csv("vd.csv", sep="\s+")
d2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars="day")
d2["sample"] = d2.groupby(["variable", "day"])["day"].rank("first")
d3 = d2.pivot_table(index=["variable", "sample"], columns="day")
```

which gives

```
>>> d3
                    value                                        
day                     1         2         3         4         5
variable sample                                                  
var1     1      -0.001285 -0.001331 -0.001362 -0.001394 -0.001467
         2      -0.001310 -0.001360 -0.001372 -0.001431 -0.001491
var2     1       0.001381  0.001375  0.001444  0.001437  0.001433
         2       0.001377  0.001430  0.001441  0.001434  0.001432
var3     1       1.022781  1.022477  1.022280  1.022017  1.021749
         2       1.022626  1.022385  1.022161  1.021908  1.021602

[6 rows x 5 columns]
```

(Although to be honest, I think Andy's way is slicker.  I'll leave this here though because the melt-modify-pivot pattern has proved pretty useful for me in the past in harder cases.)

Comment: Thanks for keeping this. TBH I think this is better, I know which one I'd prefer to read (stack/unstack are indecipherable)

Comment: I think that skippers ``wide_to_long`` might actually do this : http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt, e.g. this is very close: ``pd.wide_to_long(df,['var1','var2','var3'],i='day',j='foo')``, but don't really understand it in the first place.....

Comment: This did the job indeed. Andy's version is very concise, which is nice in my opinion, but I find it a bit harder to read and it doesn't keep the samples in order. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use groupby's cumcount to create a column to track if it's first or second:

```
In [11]: df['occurrence'] = df.groupby('day').cumcount()

In [12]: df = df.set_index(['day', 'occurrence'])
```

Now you can do a bit of stacking and unstacking:

```
In [13]: df.stack(0).unstack(0)
Out[13]: 
day                     1         2         3         4         5
occurrence                                                       
0          var1 -0.001285 -0.001331 -0.001362 -0.001394 -0.001467
           var2  0.001381  0.001375  0.001444  0.001437  0.001433
           var3  1.022781  1.022477  1.022280  1.022017  1.021749
1          var1 -0.001310 -0.001360 -0.001372 -0.001431 -0.001491
           var2  0.001377  0.001430  0.001441  0.001434  0.001432
           var3  1.022626  1.022385  1.022161  1.021908  1.021602
```

Comment: I prefer @DSM's way (more robust)! Which levels to stack/unstack is not very readable...