# Clean way of slicing + stacking pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a Pandas DataFrame, say df, which is 1099 lines by 33 rows. I need the original file to be processed by another software, but it is not in the proper format. This is why I'm trying to get the good format whith pandas.

The problem is very simple: df is constituted by columns of identifiers (7 in the real case, only 3 in the following example), and then by corresponding results by months. To be clear, it's like

```
A    B    C    date1result  date2result  date2result
a1   b1   c1       12           15           17
a2   b2   c3        5            8            3
```

But to be processed, I would need it to have one line per result, adding a column for the date. In the given example, it would be

```
A    B    C      result       date  
a1   b1   c1       12         date1 
a1   b1   c1       15         date2
a1   b1   c1       17         date3
a2   b2   c3        5         date1
a2   b2   c3        8         date2
a2   b2   c3        3         date3
```

So to be more precise, I have edited manually all column names with date (after the read_excel, the looked like '01/01/2015 0:00:00' or something like that, and I was unable to access them... As a secondary question, does anyone knows how to access columns being imported from a date field in an .xlsx?), so that date column names are now 2015_01, 2015_02... 2015_12, 2016_01, ..., 2016_12, the 5 first being 'Account','Customer Name','Postcode','segment' and 'Rep'. So I tried the following code:

```
core = df.loc[:,('Account','Customer Name','Postcode','segment','Rep')]

df_final=pd.Series([])
for year in [2015,2016]:
    for month in range(1, 13):
        label = "%i_%02i" % (year,month)
        date = []
        for i in range(core.shape[0]):
            date.append("01/%02i/%i"%(month,year))  
        df_date=pd.Series(date) #I don't know to create this 1xn df
        df_final = df_final.append(pd.concat([core, df[label], df_date], axis=1))
```

That works roughly, but it is very unclean: I get a (26376, 30) shaped df_final, fist column being the dates, then the results, but of course with '2015_01' as column name, then all the '2015_02' through '2016_12' filled by NaN, and at last my Account', 'Customer Name', 'Postcode', 'segment' and 'Rep' columns. Does anyone know how I could do such a "slicing+stacking" in a clean way?

Thank you very much.

Edit: it is roughly the reverse of this question: [Stacking and shaping slices of DataFrame (pandas) without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719649/stacking-and-shaping-slices-of-dataframe-pandas-without-looping)

Comment: It's roughly the reverse question of this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719649/stacking-and-shaping-slices-of-dataframe-pandas-without-looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ithink you need [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C'], value_name='result', var_name='date')
print (df)
    A   B   C         date  result
0  a1  b1  c1  date1result      12
1  a2  b2  c3  date1result       5
2  a1  b1  c1  date2result      15
3  a2  b2  c3  date2result       8
4  a1  b1  c1  date3result      17
5  a2  b2  c3  date3result       3
```

And then convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print (df)
    A   B   C  2015_01  2016_10  2016_12
0  a1  b1  c1       12       15       17
1  a2  b2  c3        5        8        3

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C'], value_name='result', var_name='date')
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y_%m')
print (df)
    A   B   C       date  result
0  a1  b1  c1 2015-01-01      12
1  a2  b2  c3 2015-01-01       5
2  a1  b1  c1 2016-10-01      15
3  a2  b2  c3 2016-10-01       8
4  a1  b1  c1 2016-12-01      17
5  a2  b2  c3 2016-12-01       3
```

Comment: Very good function, thank you! Do you know how I could also change the values in 'variable' column from 2015_01, ..., 2016_12 to 01/01/2015 ... to 01/12/2016 in the same time?

Comment: Of course, and thak you again! I'm reading melt() doc, it's very powerful! :) :) :)

Comment: Just one thing: melt works on the mock example, but when I perform it on the real data, instead of my dates to be converted, I get 'Customer Area'. Do you know why?

Comment: I think you need add all columns which are not contain dates to `id_vars`. If it doesnt work question is - What is difference between your sample and your real data?

Comment: I simply hadn't take all the columns from the original df (there where more than 7), that's why. Everything works perfectly now, thank you so much!!! :)